# Taking screen shots from TV while playing streams from storage (not live content)

Tags: android, video, screenshot

I want to take screen shots from a smart TV(android platform) while playing videos from internal or external storage(**not live feed) using **adb screencast** feature.I have disabled "hardware overlay" and followed everything I could find on the Internet but the screenshots of the video are only a black background.

I can take proper screenshots of every other thing except the video part.Please help.I want to know if the same is an inherent limitation or it can be achieved somehow.